# JAVAFX pass information from one scene to another not displayed in the gui

Tags: user-interface, javafx

In my application, I pass user name from login scene to the main scene. The information passed successfully but not displayed in the gui.
Before I switch scene, I do this to pass the user name to the Main controller:

```
    try 
    {
        URL location = getClass().getResource("Main.fxml");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream());
        LogInController ctrl = fxmlLoader.getController();
        ctrl.setUserDetails(userName);
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(MainWindowController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The setUserDetails method in the Main controller:

```
void setUserDetails(String userName) 
{
    System.out.println(userName);  //working
    nameLabel.setText(userName);   //do nothing !!
}
```

And then I display the Main scene..
The name is printed in the console but not display in the gui. what should I do? Do I need to repaint or refresh the scene? If yes, then how can I do it? TNX

Comment: What is the [rest of the code in your controller and fxml](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Are you (incorrectly) writing something like [@FXML nameLabel = new Label()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960625/menubutton-doesnt-display-items-in-javafx?answertab=active#tab-top)?

Comment: No I did not..  and the rest of the code is huge :(

Comment: You should read the mcve link I provided and come up with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I didnt know I need to set the scene's root to the Parent I created with the fxmlLoader.load().